# Where can I find modern account of Macartney Embassy to China (1792–1794)?

Tags: china, british-empire, 18th-century, qing-dynasty

[Macartney Embassy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macartney_Embassy) was the first British diplomatic mission to China. It was such an important but little-known event. I read quite some Chinese materials but not many English materials. The wiki article is probably the only English article I read and this video clip called "[The Macartney Expedition and the Global Economy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zf7TQ99EHUw&t=395s)" was the only clip I can find on youtube.

Actually I can buy a book series called "An Authentic Account of an Embassy from the King of Great Britain to the Emperor of China" by the mission members George Macartney and George Staunton [at amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0353607304)! But there are more than 3000 pages, written more than 200 years ago and I don't think I will read them.  Even if I buy them, they will just clutter my study and collect dust. So are there any modern accounts of Macartney Embassy, books, documentaries ?

--- update ---

I did find a modern account of Macartney Embassy, check here https://www.erudit.org/en/journals/lumen/2013-v32-lumen0563/1015486ar/abstract/

I briefly read it, I did not find anything I have not known from the Chinese materials I read. But for those don't know Macartney Embassy before may take a look.

Comment: Wait, so you've already found the best and most complete account of the thing you are asking about, and you want Cliffs Notes or a youtube video?

Comment: The best account of Shackleton's Trans-Antarctic Expedition is not Shackleton's own account "South" but Alfred Lansing's book "Endurance".  The "An Authentic Account" series were written more than 200 years ago. So my question "modern account"

Comment: Besides, I already said those books have more 3000 pages and English is not my native language so I don't think I will read them.

Comment: The original book can actually be read through the [Yale University Library website](https://collections.library.yale.edu/catalog/16776974), as well as through Google Books (at least in the USA;  not sure about where you are.)

Comment: Also, because of the format of this site it's best to ask one question at a time.  I would recommend you edit this question to delete the question about the quote, and make a separate post to ask that.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the second question as you suggested. And I am in China of course lol.

Comment: Also: I was able to find the original text of the quote on p. 412–413 of [this book.](https://archive.org/details/someaccountofpub02barr/page/412/mode/2up)  If you can't access it from where you are, post a separate question and I'll post the text as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132195/discussion-between-qiulang--and-michael-seifert).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I have asked a separate question https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66806/what-was-lord-macartneys-original-words-about-chinese-under-qianlong-emperors

Comment: There is a book named "Our first ambassador to China" which was probably written by a family member in 1908. Not sure if that helps.I am reasonably sure there are a number of scientific papers on that mission. Have you tried looking it up in the Cambridge History of China yet?

Comment: I didn't know "Our first ambassador to China" and I have not tried Cambridge History of China. That may get me somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look through the references of the Wikipedia article, especially [the book by Hevia](http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=51A281B806FA9582837C2A2BAA830755)?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I did find another article (other than the wiki article) today. I have updated my question.